# PHP switch, why doesn't this work?

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement

I have a strange problem that I can't seem to solve. I've quite a complicated bit of code going on, but I've simplified it and the problem still exists.

See the following:

```
<?php
$meta = array('meta_title' => 'correct');

switch (true) {
    case empty($meta['meta_description']):
        $meta['meta_description'] = 'incorrect';
    case empty($meta['meta_keywords']):
        $meta['meta_keywords'] = 'incorrect';
    case empty($meta['meta_title']):
        $meta['meta_title'] = 'incorrect';
}

print_r($meta);
```

Now for some reason, his returns meta_title as incorrect eventhough its clearly set in the array. It's almost as if its ignoring the case and just dropping down.

I've set up an example at: http://codepad.org/mQH9Kf1L

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

It might make more sense to see where I'm using this. See the following:
http://codepad.org/WnxBp8Nt (line 43 onwards)

Just out of interest, I changed I added a quick microtimer and tested this version and a version written with seperate ifs. The if version came out a little slower.

Comment: +1 for simplyfying your code into a usable example.

Comment: You are forgetting to `break` at the end of each case.

Comment: Agree with Nanne - People don't realize how important that is :)

Comment: Though people commenting might be right you can do it in all sorts of ways, this interests me. Why doesn't this work? If you remove the 2 other cases the `true == empty(blah)` does work as expected, but when the othere emptys are there, it doesn't.. bugs me  ;)

Comment: exactly what I was thinking. I actually wrote it another way, but was just messing around trying to get shorter code. Interesting if you add meta_description and meta_keywords to the array, none of them fire.

Comment: Actually if you check the PHP manual for the switch statement you will find this behavior explained by example. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php scroll to the part that starts with **"It is important to understand how the switch statement is executed in order to avoid mistakes."** They have an example that clearly matches your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's not doing what you want is because if case 1 is true, cases 2 & 3 trigger automatically (and if case 2 is true, case 3 always fire). This is not what `switch` is for. You really just need 3 separate `if` clauses:

```
<?php
$meta = array('meta_title' => 'correct');

if (empty($meta['meta_description']))
        $meta['meta_description'] = 'incorrect';
if (empty($meta['meta_keywords']))
        $meta['meta_keywords'] = 'incorrect';
if (empty($meta['meta_title']))
        $meta['meta_title'] = 'incorrect';

print_r($meta);
```

Comment: So you're saying that if you don't break every code following will be executed without checking if their case? .. that's... unexpected...

Comment: Ah I thought that was the problem. Does that not seem strange behavious though? I would have thought it would drop and test the next case without a break!

Comment: Not unexpected - that's exactly what `switch` is for. If you don't mean it to do that, you should not be using `switch`. It's used to replace a long if/elseif/elseif/else, not a series of independent if statements

Comment: completely makes sense now, and explains the microtimer result!

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [PHP Documentation for Switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

> It is important to understand how the switch statement is executed in
>   order to avoid mistakes. The switch statement executes line by line
>   (actually, statement by statement). In the beginning, no code is
>   executed. Only when a case statement is found with a value that
>   matches the value of the switch expression does PHP begin to execute
>   the statements. PHP continues to execute the statements until the end
>   of the switch block, or the first time it sees a break statement. If
>   you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement
>   list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case.

What you are actually trying to do is:

```
<?php
$meta = array('meta_title' => 'correct');

switch (true) {
    case empty($meta['meta_description']):
        $meta['meta_description'] = 'incorrect';
}
switch (true) {
    case empty($meta['meta_keywords']):
        $meta['meta_keywords'] = 'incorrect';
}
switch (true) {
    case empty($meta['meta_title']):
        $meta['meta_title'] = 'incorrect';
}

print_r($meta);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember to `break`:

```
$meta = array('meta_title' => 'correct');

switch (true) {
    case empty($meta['meta_description']):
        $meta['meta_description'] = 'incorrect';
        break;
    case empty($meta['meta_keywords']):
        $meta['meta_keywords'] = 'incorrect';
        break;
    case empty($meta['meta_title']):
        $meta['meta_title'] = 'incorrect';
        break;
}

print_r($meta);
```

Also the above makes ***no sense***.

You **should not** use a switch statement for the above.

Try using `if...elseif...`:

```
if(empty($meta['meta_description']))
    $meta['meta_description'] = 'incorrect';
elseif(empty($meta['meta_keywords']))
    $meta['meta_keywords'] = 'incorrect';
elseif(empty($meta['meta_title']))
    $meta['meta_title'] = 'incorrect';
```

Comment: If I break though, it breaks the logic. I really am using each case as 3 seperate ifs, and just looking for a way to shorten the code.

Answer (score 1):

Break won't solve the problem. If/else won't work since many needs. Also your code make no sense. You ever heard of foreach ?

```
<?php
$MetaDefault = array('meta_description', 'meta_title', 'meta_keywords');

$Meta = array('meta_title' => 'correct');

foreach($MetaDefault as $Row){
    if(!isset($Meta[$Row])){
        $Meta[$Row] = 'incorrect';
    }
}

print_r($Meta);
?>
```

If you break, it will quit the switch.
Your others variables won't be test.
If/else will do the same.

Comment: I could do that, but thats alot of lines. It's not that I couldn't do it another away, I just wondered why the third case is validating as true and running the next line (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

Once a single `case` is true, all other following code in the switch block is executed *except other `case` statements*.  See the [php documentation for the `switch` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

> The switch statement executes line by line (actually, statement by statement). In the beginning, no code is executed. Only when a case statement is found with a value that matches the value of the switch expression does PHP begin to execute the statements. PHP continues to execute the statements until the end of the switch block, or the first time it sees a break statement. If you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case.

So what happens here is the following:

```
switch (true) {
    case empty($meta['meta_description']): // MATCH
        $meta['meta_description'] = 'incorrect';  // EXECUTE
    case empty($meta['meta_keywords']): // SKIP
        $meta['meta_keywords'] = 'incorrect'; // EXECUTE
    case empty($meta['meta_title']): // SKIP
        $meta['meta_title'] = 'incorrect'; // EXECUTE
}
```

Note that the following `case` statement bodies are *not* executed at all:

```
switch(true) {
    case false:
        echo "Not Executed\n";
    case true:
        echo "Executed\n";
    case print("Condition Not Executed\n"):
        echo "Also Executed\n";
}
```

This will print:

```
Executed
Also Executed
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have any `break` statements. Add one to each case and it will work.

What's happening is that the first case (`empty($meta['meta_description'])`) is evaluating to `true` and without any `break` statements, the code for the rest of the cases are executed as well, so `meta_keywords` is set to incorrect and so is `meta_title`.

Given that this is how `switch` statements work, you are probably not looking to use a `switch` statement. You are probably looking for something more like this:

```
$meta = array('meta_title' => 'correct');

if (empty($meta['meta_description']))
    $meta['meta_description'] = 'incorrect';
if (empty($meta['meta_keywords']))
    $meta['meta_keywords'] = 'incorrect';
if (empty($meta['meta_title']))
    $meta['meta_title'] = 'incorrect';

print_r($meta);
```

Or you could use a loop:

```
$meta = array('meta_title' => 'correct');

$properties = array('meta_description', 'meta_keywords', 'meta_title');
foreach ($properties as $property)
{
    if (empty($meta[$property]))
        $meta[$property] = 'incorrect';
}

print_r($meta);
```

Both of these should produce the same result, but the loop will be easier and shorter if you have more properties.

Comment: if I do that though, then I'm interesting a loop into the equation though, and then an if, which can't be as performance efficient?

Comment: Why would the code for other cases fire, if their condition shouldn't The fact that you need a break to not execute the other 'legs' is obvious, but that's not the answer, is it? If it wouldn't evaluate the other 'legs', but just execute ALL the code, that looks like a bug, doesn't it?

Comment: @JamesLeckenby: A loop is not a bad thing. This is exactly what loops are made for. Any performance hit taken by using a loop in this case would be absolutely negligible.

Comment: @Nanne: You should read up on how `switch` statements work. This isn't just how it works in PHP, it works this way in most (if not all) C derived languages. This is commonly referred to as "falling through." All code on the following "legs" will execute until a `break` statement is reached.